# Change status Bar color in Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How to change status bar to a different color than the navigation bar using Xamarin Forms in iOS.
I have no problem changing status bar in android but do not know how to do it in iOS, can someone guide me with this please.

Comment: Look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NQ9ttm_UEw&ab_channel=DavidOrtinau

Comment: I tried the video before asking here also checked out a few articles but nothing worked for me, what i want to do is set the nav bar to blue and status bar to orange, is there a way to implement it?